# how to extract the fourth column in large datasets in R

Tags: r

```
EPI_ISL_14694|A/duck/Bavaria/2/1977|A_/_H1N1|MP|1977-01-01
EPI_ISL_14816|A/turkey/England/647/1977|A_/_H7N7|NP|1977-01-01
EPI_ISL_14694|A/duck/Bavaria/2/1977|A_/_H1N1|HA|1977-01-01
EPI_ISL_16158|A/duck/Hokkaido/W132/2004|A_/_H12N5|MP|2004-10-24
EPI_ISL_16158|A/duck/Hokkaido/W132/2004|A_/_H12N5|PB2|2004-10-24
```

I am trying to extract the gene segment into a column in my dataframe but no headway yet.
Any suggestion on what to improve  on the script

```
df <- data.frame(Isolate_Id=gsub("\\|.*","",names(gisaid.aiv.fasta)),segment=gsub(".*\\|","",names(gisaid.aiv.fasta)),segment_seqs=as.character(gisaid.aiv.fasta))
```

This scripts brings my last column as the segment but I want it to return the fourth column as the segment.
Thank you

```
new("DNAStringSet", pool = 
new("SharedRaw_Pool", xp_list = list(
<pointer: 0x0>), 
.link_to_cached_object_list = 
list(<environment>)), 
ranges = new("GroupedIRanges", group = 
c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L), start = c(1L, 1439L, 3148L, 
4672L, 6887L, 9204L), 
    width = c(1438L, 1709L, 1524L, 2215L, 2317L, 2304L), 
    NAMES = c("EPI_ISL_10367|A/duck/Nanjing/01/1999|A_/_H9N2|NA|1999-01-01", 
    "EPI_ISL_10367|A/duck/Nanjing/01/1999|A_/_H9N2|HA|1999-01-01", 
    "EPI_ISL_10367|A/duck/Nanjing/01/1999|A_/_H9N2|NP|1999-01-01", 
    "EPI_ISL_10367|A/duck/Nanjing/01/1999|A_/_H9N2|PA|1999-01-01", 
    "EPI_ISL_10367|A/duck/Nanjing/01/1999|A_/_H9N2|PB1|1999-01-01", 
    "EPI_ISL_10367|A/duck/Nanjing/01/1999|A_/_H9N2|PB2|1999-01-01"
    ), elementType = "ANY", elementMetadata = NULL, metadata = list()), 
elementType = "DNAString", elementMetadata = NULL, metadata = list())
```

Comment: which is the gene segment?

Comment: Maybe have a look at `strsplit` .

Comment: MP,NP column
the fourth column
The current code is giving me the last column which is not what am looking for

Comment: So something like this? `sapply(strsplit(x, "\\|"), "[", 4)` assuming that x is a vector with strings

Comment: It isn't clear if that's the contents of a `character` vector, a file, or something else.

Comment: If that is a string (newlines embedded, perhaps), then `read.table(text="EPI_.....10-40", sep="|")[,4]`

Comment: JoyA, please [edit] your question and add the output from `dput(head(gisaid.aiv.fasta))` to a [code block]. Thanks!

Comment: When using `sub` maybe: `sub("([^|]+\\|){3}([^|]+).*", "\\2", "EPI_ISL_14694|A/duck/Bavaria/2/1977|A_/_H1N1|MP|1977-01-01")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Edit*: your object appears to be a bit more complex than a string ... but fortunately I think we can use

```r
nms <- names(gisaid.aiv.fasta)
```

to get what we *need*: a vector of strings. From there, we can use either of the following:

```r
read.table(text = nms, sep = "|")
#              V1                        V2        V3  V4         V5
# 1 EPI_ISL_14694     A/duck/Bavaria/2/1977  A_/_H1N1  MP 1977-01-01
# 2 EPI_ISL_14816 A/turkey/England/647/1977  A_/_H7N7  NP 1977-01-01
# 3 EPI_ISL_14694     A/duck/Bavaria/2/1977  A_/_H1N1  HA 1977-01-01
# 4 EPI_ISL_16158 A/duck/Hokkaido/W132/2004 A_/_H12N5  MP 2004-10-24
# 5 EPI_ISL_16158 A/duck/Hokkaido/W132/2004 A_/_H12N5 PB2 2004-10-24
read.table(text = nms, sep = "|")[,c(1,4)]
#              V1  V4
# 1 EPI_ISL_14694  MP
# 2 EPI_ISL_14816  NP
# 3 EPI_ISL_14694  HA
# 4 EPI_ISL_16158  MP
# 5 EPI_ISL_16158 PB2
```

or

```r
sapply(strsplit(nms, "\\|"), `[[`, 4)
# [1] "MP"  "NP"  "HA"  "MP"  "PB2"
```

for just the fourth column.

Comment: Thanks @r2evans
I actually want the first column,4th column and the sequence fasta inside my dataframe

Comment: See my edit, Joy A, I _think_ it'll work in your case.